# Jquery Image Change -- iterating through images

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a set of classes that I want to integrate through, like this:

.g1 ---> .g12

How would I do that?

I have the increment thing I want to do and I believe I've written it properly, but I don't know how to concatenate that variable with the .grain so I can change only one square per click.

```
$("#grains").click(function(){
var x;
x++;
$(".grain").attr('src',"orangesq-01.png");
});
```

Here's the list item I made:

```
<ul id="grains">
            <li><img src="blusq-01.png" class="grain" /></li>
            <li><img src="blusq-01.png" class="grain1" /></li>
            <li><img src="blusq-01.png" class="grain2" /></li>
            <li><img src="blusq-01.png" class="grain3" /></li>
            <li><img src="blusq-01.png" class="grain4" /></li>
            <li><img src="blusq-01.png" class="grain5" /></li>
            <li><img src="blusq-01.png" class="grain6" /></li>
            <li><img src="blusq-01.png" class="grain7" /></li>
            <li><img src="blusq-01.png" class="grain8" /></li>
            <li><img src="blusq-01.png" class="grain9" /></li>
            <li><img src="blusq-01.png" class="grain10" /></li>
            <li><img src="blusq-01.png" class="grain11" /></li>
        </ul>
```

I think you get the idea of what I'm trying to do. If I could figure out that concatenating thing, it would be awesome.

Comment: do you want to change the src of all the images to orangesq-01.png? or you want to do something like grain2 --> orangesq-02.png?

Comment: Just a tip: use ID's where possible. JQuery is quicker with ID's than classes. Seems like you should rename all your classes to 'grain'?

Comment: @Chango: I want to change all the src to orangesq-01.

Comment: @Danny: That is a good idea, but if I do that, it makes all of the blue squares orange and I only want to change one square per click in the list item set.

Comment: @omochan: using JQuery's eq() function will allow you to select them individually, allowing you to name them all with one class. Makes CSS and JQuery much easier.

Answer (score 2):

You can just append the index or just use the `.eq()` call if they are in order already.

```
var x = 0;
$("#grains").click(function(){
 $(".grain" + (x === 0 ? '' : x)).attr('src',"orangesq-01.png");
 //or
 $(this).find('img').eq(x).attr('src',"orangesq-01.png");
  x++;
});
```

Heh http://jsfiddle.net/mURxA/

Comment: does he need to move `var x` outside the click function as well?

Comment: Also he doesn't have just the class `grain` throughout. So he'll need to change that, or you can just get the images by element instead.

Comment: @Jack I try to just answer his specific question, you can't know what else he is using the classes for from just a snippet.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'll try it out and post what happens!

Comment: Remember that if you use the second method (I prefer that one) all the  images should have the same class ('grain'): http://jsfiddle.net/tfAtx/

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, more dynamic approach, would be use a custom selector in conjunction with `eq(0)` to simply select the first image, like so:

```
$('#grains').click(function()
{
    $('img[src="blusq-01.png"]', this).eq(0).attr('src', 'orangesq-01.png');
});
```

*Hope you don't mind Andrew, I updated your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/GeekyEggo/mURxA/1/).*

Comment: so this would just make any blue square I click an orange one? Not trying to be annoyingly stupid, but I'm still in the shallow end of these waters, so I don't know the whole of how jquery calls work yet. Trans: I will probably ask the most seemingly basic questions about [everything].

Comment: That's okay; what this will do is upon the element `#grains` being clicked, select all `img` with the blue image as their src, within the scope of the clicked `#grains` element. This is done by specifying the container, which is the 2nd parameter in the $(..., container) call, aka `this`. We're then selecting the first element in the collection, as they're in DOM order, using the `eq(0)` and simply updating its `src`. :)